# Sense and purpose of anti-demon possesion symbol?

Tags: plot-explanation, supernatural

In the television series, Supernatural, throughout the series it is shown that Sam and Dean have a symbol at their chest to protect themselves from possession by deamons.

But in S08E02, it is shown that a deamon can burm the symbol and possess a person.

My question is, What is the whole purpose and sense of the seal at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually a demon **did not** burn the symbol off, it was Nike (or a god like Nike).  Yes the symbol can be destroyed, but we're not certain if it can be done by a demon or if only certain people (like the old gods) can do it.

If it CAN be burned off by anyone, it still would be somewhat hard to accomplish since the demon would have to get close to detroy the lock, then leave it's current body and posses its target.